# Programmatically creating PDF from webpage

Tags: css, google-chrome, pdf, printing, resume

I have my resume online in an html page (www.mysite.com/resume.html). Every time I need a PDF version of it, I use Google Chrome's print dialog to save it as a PDF, which uses my print CSS stylesheet.

I want to be able to navigate to www.mysite.com/resume.pdf to always have an up to date PDF version without having to go through Google Chrome manually. Is there a way to programmatically and automatically create a resume.pdf from resume html? If I can write a script that runs once every 24 hours or something like that, that would be good.

Comment: hold up, how often do you alter your resume?!

Comment: Are you using any serverside programming/script language like ASP, PHP, Java...?

Comment: Pretty often... Mostly just small changes or changing the wording

Comment: @LinusCaldwell yeah, PHP, more specifically Wordpress

Comment: Well, then it might be better to ask google how to create pdfs with php (or wordpress). If you have problems then, ask here.

Comment: Just use a cron job to convert it with pandoc.

Answer (score 11):

PhantomJS is perfect for this. It invokes an instance of WebKit from the command line which can then be used to output to file such as PDF.

PhantomJS:

http://phantomjs.org/

Specific instructions for exporting screen output to a file:

http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

e.g.:

```
phantomjs rasterize.js 'http://www.example.com/resume.html' resume.pdf
```

Comment: This won't be copying textual data into the PDF document. This seems more on lines of outputting screenshot to PDF, is that right? In that case, Accessibility of PDF would go for a toss.

Answer (score 8):

Chrome has started [headless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) program.

With that, we can create a pdf. e.g. for windows navigate your commandline to

```
C:\Users\{{your_username}}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application>
```

Then hit the command:

```
chrome --headless --print-to-pdf="d:\\{{path and file name}}.pdf" https://google.com
```

Comment: I tried this out. But even in this answer's case, Accessibility tagging went for a toss. I supplied a URL of an Accessible website conforming to #WCAG norms but on converting, heading structure was lost.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do this server-side via PHP might I recommend the [Browsershot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot) library which leverages the [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) (NodeJS package) and Chrome / Chromium headless browser?

It works really well. Way easier to install and get going than [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) (which is another option that doesn't rely on a NodeJS package nor the Chrome/Chromium headless browser. Personally, I recommend Browsershot solution since wkhtmltopdf has some issues depending on the type of server (Linux distro and version) you're running. That is, the only reliable way to install wkhtmltopdf that I've found is to download and compile from source on the server that you're running and not through a package manager).

Also, if you happen to be needing a solution specifically while working on a Laravel project then there's a [wrapper library for Browsershot](https://github.com/verumconsilium/laravel-browsershot) available.

Check out [this tutorial](https://murze.be/easily-convert-webpages-to-images-using-php) to get started.